# Overfitting in Huggingface's TFBertForSequenceClassification

Tags: overfitting, bert, huggingface

I'm using Huggingface's TFBertForSequenceClassification for multilabel tweets classification. During training the model archives good accuracy, but the validation accuracy is poor. I've tried to solve the overfitting using some dropout but the performance is still poor. The model is as follows:

```
# Get and configure the BERT model
config = BertConfig.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", hidden_dropout_prob=0.5, num_labels=13)
bert_model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", config=config)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5, epsilon=0.00015, clipnorm=0.01)
loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
metric = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')

bert_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=[metric])
bert_model.summary()
```

The summary is as follows:

[image: Bert Model summary]

When I fit the model, the outcome is:

```
history = bert_model.fit(train_ds, epochs=30, validation_data = test_ds)
```

[image] [image]

Comment: It likely just has way too much capacity for the dataset you are trying to use.  You could increase the dropout / regularization, but less layers / stacks would also likely help, or decrease the dimension of the vectors in the transformer (not sure what options BERT has).  That would be my plan.  With 100M parameters, it's probably just reproducing your input exactly.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it is better to build your own classifier using a BERT model and adding 2-3 layers to the model for classification purpose. As the builtin sentiment classifier use only a single layer. But for better generalization your model should be deeper with proper regularization. As you have around 13 class you should use deeper model with a good number of training examples for each class.